# Controller doesn't store nested attribute params in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

Showing View code below. Also showing the response params response after submitting the form.

```
<%= f.fields_for :investor_profile_interests do |ipi| %>
    <%= ipi.collection_check_boxes(:investor_interest, InvestorInterest.all, :id, :interest) do |b| %>
      <p>
        <label>
          <span class="iblock mr4"><%= b.check_box %></span>
           <span><%= b.text %></span>
         </label>
       </p>
 <% end %>
```

The response params after submitting i am getting in arrays. I can't save the response in database. **investor_profile** table is updating whereas **investor_profile_interests** model it is not getting updated? Something is wrong in my controller codes i think. Can you please help me on this? Thanks. Controller codes below.

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0K+YjslW9JDGJSlhfQlb+X3grkgm/HlAnz4mt3CVHVA1dGS1mpnE1qXR7uIVqRSlotY4J1gqIKTn/KPZxH4UyQ==", "investor_profile"=>{"investor_profile_interests_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"investor_interest"=>["", "1", "2"]}}, "position"=>"Bank"}, "commit"=>"Submit", "controller"=>"investor_profiles", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

**controller code**

```
 def create
    @investor_profile = current_user.investor_profiles.build(investor_profile_params)
    @investor_profile.save
    redirect_to @investor_profile
  end
```

[image: Here is the params submitted.]

Comment: You also have to permit nested attributes probably in your `investor_profile_params` method.
Also you should not build investor_profiles again in you create method. Just use new and save here.

Comment: @ParakhGarg Yes i have added it to the strong params like this and used **new** instead of **build**. Still only **investor_profile** is saved. **investor_profile_interests** is not saving. params.require(:investor_profile).permit(investor_profile_interest_attributes: [:id, :investor_profile_id, :investor_interest_id])

Comment: Do i have to add a **investor_profile_interests_controller** and add a create method there too for saving that? Right now there is no such controller.

Comment: Check your params, you have `investor_interest` key for `investor_profile_interests_attributes` but have not permitted that. This might be the reason. Try adding `investor_interest` in your strong parameter nested attributes

Comment: Try this - `params.require(:investor_profile).permit(investor_profile_interest_attributes: [:id, :investor_profile_id, :investor_interest_id, :investor_interest]) `

Comment: You don't have to create a investor_profile_interests_controller and methods, as you are using nested form and accept_nested_attributes_for, the child object will created automatically with parent.

Comment: Ok. Added **investor_interest** to the strong params too. Still only **investor_profile** updates. **investor_profile_interests* is not updating.

Comment: Here is the params that is passed after submit. https://imgur.com/a/0vVkrhs

Comment: Looks like you don't need nested attributes here at all. Please, add correponding models with associations to the question